# The element does not meet the requirement is included in the array

Tags: excel, vba

I created an array to dynamically search content in column I in worksheet "gun inventory" and put corresponding information in column B into the array. Then I display these data in the array on the list created.

As you can see from my code, my condition is text in column I is "In Tool". However the last element in array does not have "In Tool" in element though still be included into the array. I have no idea why this happen and I will be appreciated if you can help.

[image]

[image]

I donno why S0007 will show here too.

Please ignore the variables undefined I defined them as public variables. The program runs well I just don't know why the last element will be included in the array.

```
Private Sub CheckGun_Click()

Dim gunarr()
Dim col As Integer

'Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(5)
'ActiveSheet.Name = "tmp"
m = 0

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("gun inventory")

    g = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "In Tool")

    Debug.Print g

    ReDim gunarr(1 To g)

    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        If .Cells(i, "I").Text = "In Tool" Then
        m = m + 1
        End If
        gunarr(m) = .Cells(i, "B")
    Next i

End With



row = UBound(gunarr) - LBound(gunarr)


'Worksheets("tmp").Range("A2").Resize(row + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(gunarr)

  With ListBox1
            .Font.Size = 10
            .ForeColor = vbBlue
            .ControlTipText = "Tools are in use"
            .ColumnHeads = True
            .ColumnCount = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
            .ColumnWidths = "80"
            .ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
            .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
            .List = gunarr()
    End With

'On Error Resume Next
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'prevent alert popping up for deleting the sheet
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tmp").Delete
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

As you can see from my code, my condition is text in column I is "In Tool". However the last element in array does not have "In Tool" in element though still be included into the array. I have no idea why this happen and I will be appreciated if you can help.

Comment: `gunarr(m)` is assigned unconditionally...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sorry I don't quite understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Read your code. There's a loop, inside the loop there's a condition, and outside the condition there's `gunarr(m)` being assigned regardless of what the condition does. You probably want to move `gunarr(m) = .Cells(i, "B")` *inside* the conditional block that's incrementing `m`. Otherwise `gunarr(m)` is being assigned for every single value of `i`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you so much!!